# Android handle overview button (pause activity)

Tags: android, android-activity

My Problem:
I have a little app with many activities and in one there is a countdown timer, which is going down till zero. But when you are in this activity and the user press the overview button (right android button) he came to the view with all the applications but the activity doesnt stop or pause, so the countdown timer doesn't stop too. In the worst case, the user open the activity again and the countdown reached zero(which means for the activity, that there will open a other activity..)

Is there a way too handle the "overview button"? (Like the back button getPressedBack())

I don't get any good google search, because the name of the right android button is "overview button" (that had i found out with google..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnPause() and onStop() should be called after pressing the "Overview" Button. Then you can stop your coundown manually. When the user return to the activity onResume() is called and you can start the coundown again.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Handle countdown stop here
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Handle countdown start here
}
```

Comment: Is there any side or something, where i can get more Information about that button or is therefore a other Name?

Comment: You dont need to handle the button. The onPause() method is called automatically every time your app lose the focus. Then you can stop the coundown in the method and start it again when onResume() is called. You can find more infos about this methods here: (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

Comment: It worked, the only problem was, that OnResume() is also could at the start from the activity, but this was easy to handle. (with a boolean)

Answer (score 0):

I think the right strategy is to check the key pressed, by ovveriding onKeyDown method on Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    i(e == yourKeyCode) {
         stopYourTimer()
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

in your case check  KeyEvent.VK_CONTEXT_MENU  on onKeyDown event and stop your timer.